# Quarkus profile-aware config isn't used in native compilation

Tags: quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I'm using quarkus [profile-aware files](https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-aware-files) to set different property values for different profiles:

- application.properties

```
quarkus.http.port=9090 # quarkus.http.port is just an example property
```

- application-staging.properties

```
quarkus.http.port=9190
```

This works if I don't enable native-image compilation: if `QUARKUS_PROFILE` environment variable is `staging`, Quarkus will pick up the correct property value (i.e. `9190`).

However, when I do native compilation (`quarkus.package.type=native`) it seems quarkus is using the default value (`9090`); the profile-aware file is ignored by the native binary. "Profile in the property name" still works (i.e. `%staging.quarkus.http.port=9190` in application.properties).

Is this the expected behavior? Or what am I missing for the native compilation to work with profile-aware files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding the following line to the `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.native.resources.includes=*.properties
```

This causes the native compilation process to include all `application-*.properties` files from the resources so Quarkus can load the correct one depending on the `QUARKUS_PROFILE` environment variable at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I've also solved the issue for yaml config files. Probably I set this wrongly the first time, but `quarkus: native: resources: includes: "*.yaml"` works now

Answer (score 0):

Using the [getting-started](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/getting-started) quickstart with the addition of `application-dummy.properties`

```
quarkus.http.port=9090
```

when I build the application with  `mvn package -DskipTests -Dquarkus.profile=dummy -Dnative`

then when I run it, it starts on port `9090` as expected

Comment: I usually don't provide quarkus profile during build, as I want to use the same artifact for staging and production. Plus, native compilation is also slower.
What would happen with maven when I don't provide `-Dquarkus.profile`? I'm using gradle btw, but I think that doesn't matter

Comment: Quarkus would use the standard profile, i.e. `prod`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!
This doesn't explain how "Profile in the property name" works though, for staging and production, without specifying quarkus profile during build.